# How do I use Material UI's Typography with React?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to React and am using Material UI to help style things. I have Grid working fine and now want to include Typography as well.

I'm importing it fine:

`import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography'`

and am now trying to use its attributes on my various elements, as per the API guide here: https://material-ui.com/system/typography/#typography

```
<span fontSize="h6.fontSize">Hello world</span>

<span fontWeight="fontWeightBold">Hello world</span>
```

But nothing happens. I don't get any errors on compilation and the above elements just print with the attributes as they appear.

How do you use Material UI's Typography in React?

Answer (score 0):

Found I had to use the Typography 'element', eg:

```
<Typography variant="h2">Something</Typography>
```

and that I was looking at a different document https://material-ui.com/components/typography/